# How can I save the ListView to restore?

Tags: android, listview

How can I save the ListView and restore it by resume? Because when i close the app all contents are delete.

Thanks for answers

public class ToDoList extends Activity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.todolist);
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addtodo);
    final ArrayList todoItems = new ArrayList();
    final ArrayAdapter aa;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    todoItems);
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    String edittext="";
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", 0);
    edittext = settings.getString("Content", edittext);
    todoItems.add(0, edittext);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
    todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

    String edittext= myEditText.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("Content",  edittext);

    myEditText.setText("");
    return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
    });
    }}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saving ListView? You have your adapter, you can always recreate your ListView by specifying same adapter for new ListView object.

Comment: Yes, could you be more clear about what you are trying to "**save**" in your ListView ?

Comment: My problem is, that when i close the app all contents are delete.

Comment: Are you making changes to a ListView's data then needing to save/recall them later on?

Answer (score 3):

According to the comment you gave - about losing data after closing application - there are few options which you have to solve your problem.

What you have to do is to store your data for further use - you can either use `SharedPreferences` or `SQLite database`.

### SharedPreferences

It is good choice for small amounts of data. If
   you're trying to store `ListView`'s content, `SharedPreferences` is
   most likely not a good option for you.

This code you can use for storing data in your `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInteger("FirstInteger", a);
editor.putInteger("SecondInteger", b);
(...)
```

And this is how you retrieve it:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", 0);
int a = settings.getInteger("FirstInteger", false);
int b = settings.getInteger("SecondInteger", false);
```

Anyway, here you can read more
   about it:
   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

### Database

Better for larger amounts of data. It is more difficult,
   but if you know basics of MySQL, you will have no problem with using
   it. There is a good tutorial about using SQLite database in android
   application:
   http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

After you have stored your data, you can then access the local storage to retrieve them, refill adapter and recreate `ListView`.

Comment: I added the SharedPreferences parts in my post, but it doesent work :(

Comment: @FabianMllr If you want us to help you, you have to be more specific! Neighter me, nor anyone else will guess what happens in your code, so tell me what's wrong? What are the errors? How exactly are you implementing it?